# Read-only variable in PHP function?

Tags: php

How to create a constant variable in a PHP function, like with a C++ **const** keyword?

```
const int t = 10;
a = 11; // compile error
```

It can be a need to increase readability without making it error-prone. For example, when one needs a shortcut for a long named object property, so he creates a variable for that, and other one modifies this variable in the middle of a function, so they get an error.

Answer (score 5):

class constant:

```
class MyClass
{
    const CONSTANT = 'constant value';

    function showConstant() {
        echo  self::CONSTANT . "\n";
    }
}
```

generally:

```
define("const_name", "const_value");
echo const_name;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php

Comment: The problem is constants should be defined in top-level scope (class),  and it's always a bad idea to pull one function's local variable to the outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

We can define an closure accessor for that property.

```
function f(ComplexObject $object)
{
    $innerName = function() use($object) {
        return $object->innerObject->attributes->name;
    }

    /**
    *  All places that use $object->innerObject->attributes->name
    *  can address is as $innerName()
    */

}
```

Note: function call has some cost, but readability and error protection usually outweighs.

Comment: This answer makes no sense. You asked about constant *variable* - there's no such thing. There's either **constant** or **variable**. Apparently, your entire problem was about something that you didn't explain well. The answer by sinaza is correct. I would suggest either deleting this whole thing to avoid confusion or asking the correct question which is about your actual problem.

Comment: No, it's not. A variable can be anywhere,  but a constant can be only in global or class scope. My question is if there is a way/workaround to have constants in function scope, to shift my work to the compiler.

Comment: This is a classic XY problem. A constant cannot exist in the scope of a function in PHP, even though there are such language capabilities in other languages. What you've done is defined an accessor in the scope of a function. That's silly, using `$innerVarName()` is absolutely no different to `$this->get('property_name');`. Using "constants" to refer to class properties is not how we do things. It's the same as trying to light a fire with a car tire. Sure, you might make it. Does it make sense - not really.

Comment: I admit it's a bad example with an object property, because it's not about it, it can be a nested array, that doesn't has getters. It's about having compiler to notice such errors, as changing variables that are not supposed to be changed. The problem is that it's not possible to change the accessed variable with it's accessor, but you can accidently overwrite the accessor itself.